# 3d surface triangulation of an open surface with CGAL

Tags: cgal, triangulation, surface

I'm a newbie to CGAL library. However, I think it's a very suitable package for what I want to do. 
I have a set of points representing a 3D surface (as shown in figure 1).[image: figure 1]
I want to fit a 3d triangulation on this surface. The surface is not closed and therefore does not occupy a volume. The code provided in [poisson_reconstruction_example.cpp](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3/Poisson_surface_reconstruction_3_2poisson_reconstruction_example_8cpp-example.html) seems appropriate for this job. But the problem is that as a part of poisson_reconstruction algorithm it closes the ends and underneath of the surface to make it a volume (see figure2). [image: figure 2] 
I was wondering:

1- **Is there a way to do the triangulation on the surface just defined by the points, without getting a closed surface which encloses a finite volume?**
This means that the final triangulation has boundary edges.
I'm happy with any Upsampling or smoothing which may be needed.

2- If the answer to the first question is no, then, **is there any way to guarantee that the input points are the vertices of the generated triangles?**

Comment: I do not see the relation between the two questions... you are chaining them.
You may want both of them separately, or none of them.

Answer (score 5):

The poisson surface reconstruction generates a close surface that interpolates the point cloud given as input. It requires as input a point set with normals.

If you need a algorithm that only uses input points in the output, you can try the [Advancing Front Surface Reconstruction](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/index.html#Chapter_Advancing_Front_Surface_Reconstruction) algorithm.

Comment: This answer does not address a main point of the OP: getting open surfaces.

Comment: It does, advancing front does generate close surfaces.

Comment: If I understand, you mean that the answer to question 1 is something like: "There is a way to do the triangulation on the surface just defined by the points. That is using the Advancing Front Surface Reconstruction algorithm, not the Poisson Surface Reconstruction algorithm".
Is this correct?

Comment: Both 1 and 2 actually.

Comment: If I read correctly the question, 1=generate an open surface 2= using only the input points on the surface. So aforementioned algorithm is doing both.

Comment: sloriot, great!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919011/generate-open-surface-mesh-from-a-set-of-3d-points) seems to show that the Advancing Front Surface Reconstruction algorithm gives a closed surface. Unless there is a chance of passing a parameter for this purpose.

Comment: It's not because one particular point set give you a close surface that it will for all input. Check out [this example](https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction/Advancing_front_surface_reconstruction_2boundaries_8cpp-example.html) for filtering faces based on their perimeters.

Comment: But then, how to control that? What determines the type of surface (open/closed) obtained? Is it documented?

Comment: By filtering out large triangles, you'll make it impossible for the algorithm to close the surface.

Comment: Sebastien, I have expanded the details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54919011/generate-open-surface-mesh-from-a-set-of-3d-points).